# Derived Types and Generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have a type that uses generics. Let's call it `FlowerDescriptor<T>` some flowers are described using numbers, others using strings etc.

so `FlowerDescriptor<int>;` `FlowerDescriptor<string>;` etc

I want a mechanism (probably extension methods) for doing 2 things

- seeing if something *is* a `FlowerDescriptor` and
- seeing what the descriptor is.

I.e.

- `FlowerDescriptor<string>.GetType().IsFlowerDescriptor == true
  string.GetType().IsFlowerDescriptor == false`.

equally I might derive from `FlowerDescriptor<int>` i.e. `class NumberedFlower: FlowerDescriptor<int>`

new NumberedFlower.GetType().IsFlowerDesriptor == true;

- as above but returns the type
  `FlowerDescriptor<string>.GetType().GetFlowerDescriptor() == typeof(string)
  FlowerDescriptor<int>.GetType().GetFlowerDescriptor() == typeof(int)
  new NumberedFlower.GetType().GetFlowerDescriptor() == typeof(int)`

I have played about with variations of `IsAssignableFrom` and it feels like that ought to work with `typeof(FlowerDescriptor<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(FlowerDescriptor<string>))`

but it doesn't work. If it add the generic type however it does.

I am currently exploring `GetInterfaces` to know available interfaces. It'd be great to actually understand what I am doing wrong too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you want to add interfaces into the mix, the only choice you have is to

1. Detect that the type is actually a `FlowerDescriptor<T>`
2. or detect that the type *inherits* from something that is a `FlowerDescriptor<T>`

Unfortunately I don't think you can use `IsAssignableFrom` when it comes to open generics which means we're left with walking the inheritance chain up to the base classes.

Here is an example piece of code that would do the right thing:

```
public static bool IsFlowerDescriptor(this Type type)
{
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FlowerDescriptor<>))
        return true;
    if (type.BaseType != null)
        return type.BaseType.IsFlowerDescriptor();

    return false;
}
```

Here's a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n9H0P9) you can experiment with.

Comment: This looks the closest.. Would this work if FlowerDesriptor wasn't the base type and/or it wasn't the immediately derrived type? i.e. can it walk the tree and find it anywhere in there.

Comment: Also, interfaces in the mix? How so.. in production it would be IFlowerDescriptor<T>

Answer (score 2):

I would not expect the string or int class to know if its a descriptor, it makes a lot more sense to get that information from the FlowerDescriptor.

That being said if you want to use reflection you could get the generic type definition from the FlowerDescriptor instance

```
FlowerDescriptor<int> f = new FlowerDescriptor<int>();
Type t = f.GetType();
Type[] typeArguments = t.GetGenericArguments();
//check if type you care about is in typeArguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would get those two values:

```
bool isFlowerDescriptor = x is FlowerDescriptor<object>;

Type descriptorType = x.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

You could wrap these in extension methods if you like.  And add null-checks etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider having a non-generic base class.  Then your structure could look like:

```
public abstract class FlowerDescriptor { }

public class FlowerDescriptor<T> : FlowerDescriptor { }

public class NumberedFlower : FlowerDescriptor<int> { }
```

Your 2 extensions would be:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsFlowerDescriptor(this object o)
    {
        return o is FlowerDescriptor;
    }

    public static Type GetFlowerDescriptor<T>(this FlowerDescriptor<T> o)
    {
        return typeof (T);
    }
}
```

and you'd use it like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new NumberedFlower().IsFlowerDescriptor());  //true
    Console.WriteLine(new NumberedFlower().GetFlowerDescriptor()); //System.Int32
}
```

Generics have an adverse effect when it comes to reflecting over and comparing types, because a `FlowerDescriptor<int>` is a different type from `FlowerDescriptor<string>`.  This is something I have not found a good rhythm for.

Comment: Thanks - but I don't want to change the implementation to suit this requirement.